# Solidity related question when i change compiler version 0.8 then through error

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

by using solidity compiler 0.8 through Explicit type conversion not allowed from "address" to "uint256".

```
for (uint idx = 0; idx < v.length; idx++){
            address signer = ecrecover(signedHash, v[idx], r[idx], s[idx]);
            require(admins[signer]);
            require(uint256(signer) > uint256(lastVoter));
            lastVoter = signer;
            emit NewCheckpointVote(_sectionIndex, _hash, v[idx], r[idx], s[idx]);

            // Sufficient signatures present, update latest checkpoint.
            if (idx+1 >= threshold){
                hash = _hash;
                height = block.number;
                sectionIndex = _sectionIndex;
                return true;
            }
        }
        // We shouldn't wind up here, reverting un-emits the events
        revert();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using newest versions of solidity compiler you must explicitly convert address to 20 bytes long value of desired type. In your case you could use `uint256(uint160(someAddress))`;